# Running a function a specified number of times

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
var nTimes = function (n, func) {
      var numberOfTimesRan = 0;
      var resultOfRunningFunc;
      return function() {
          if (numberOfTimesRan < n) {
              resultOfRunningFunc = func.apply(null, arguments);
              numberOfTimesRan++;
              return resultOfRunningFunc;
          }
          return resultOfRunningFunc;
      }
      return resultOfRunningFunc;
  }
  var column = function(board) {
      var counter = 0;
      var checker = {};      
      for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        var key = board[i][counter];
        checker[key] = '';
      }
      counter++;
      if (Object.keys(checker).length !== 9) {
          return "Try again!";
      }
  }

nTimes(9, column);

var result2 = column([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
                      [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9],
                      [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
                      [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
                      [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
                      [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
                      [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
                      [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
                      [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]]) //, "Try again!")
console.log(result2)
```

Im new to JavaScript and im trying to practice closures. What I want is to run the column function 9 times. Currently in the nTimes function func is getting called on column and the right argument is getting passed in but nTimes is only getting ran once. Any advice on how i can fix it to get it to keep running?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `nTimes` as used below to run a function multiple times.

```js
function nTimes(count, func) {
  for (x=0;count>=x;x++) {
    func;
  }
}
function testFunc(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}

nTimes(9, testFunc("Hello World!"));
```

This is a simpler version to the one you were trying to use. Your function did not work once you use `return` the code instantly exits out of the function, meaning the code below it fill not work.

Comment: AHH okay yeah that makes sense! I made it work with what you showed me, thank you! But lets just say the function that was getting passed to nTimes was getting passed arguments then i would have to use the .apply function?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nTimes(count, func) {
  for (x=0;count>=x;x++) {
    func;
  }
}
function testFunc(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}

nTimes(9, testFunc("Hello World!"));
```

I tried this code, but it logs "Hello world" only once for me, I changed it for this implemantaion and it works for me.

```
    function nTimes(count, func) {
  for (x=0;count>=x;x++) {
    func();
  }
}
function testFunc(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}

nTimes(9, testFunc.bind(null, "Hello World!"));
```